# Unity switcher theme

Tags: unity, application-switcher

Is it possible to modify the Unity switcher theme and behavior? Namely: no 3D "rolling" and no icon borders.

[image]

I love the gnome-shell's, but unity is better for me.

[image]

Are there any 3rd party switchers? I need it to group my apps (like both Unity and GNOME-Shell do) and that's pretty much it.

*Images taken from http://www.bohemianalps.com/blog/2011/how-to-switch-from-unity-to-gnome-3-on-ubuntu-11-10/, thanks.*

Comment: There's no way to customize it. The theme's a bit better in 13.04 though.

Answer (score 0):

You can install some other switcher using `ccsm`, by now I think that there is not much that you can change with unity default switcher, except some small theming options. I tried to find switcher options in theme (I tested `Adwaita` and `Radiance`), but no success. I couldn't find css attributes to change.